# Doppler effect for moving receiver and moving transmitter

Tags: vectors, doppler-effect

For the case that receiver and transmitter are moving, the shift in frequency is given with

$$f_{receiver} = f_{transmitter}  \frac{c + v_{receiver}}{c - v_{transmitter}}$$

if they approach each other or

$$f_{receiver} = f_{transmitter}  \frac{c - v_{receiver}}{c + v_{transmitter}}$$

if they move away from each other.

How can I calculate whether both objects are approaching or not? I have the position vectors $\vec{r}_{receiver}$ and $\vec{r}_{transmitter}$ and velocity vectors $\vec{v}_{receiver}$ and $\vec{v}_{transmitter}$.

This seems like a simple task, but I only come up with checking whether $|\vec{r}_{receiver} - \vec{r}_{transmitter}|$ is bigger than $|(\vec{r}_{receiver} + \vec{v}_{receiver}) - (\vec{r}_{transmitter} + \vec{v}_{transmitter})|$, but this does not work for close points or large velocities.

Comment: I don't think that your formula is applicable to EM waves because the speed of light is absolute and the transmitter moving towards the receiver or the receiver moving towards the transmitter are identical and should give identical results.

Comment: Have a look at the relativistic effect. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect